# Функции получения символа по коду ASCII и наоборот.

Tags: winapi, embarcadero, c++

Есть ли функцию, с помощью которой можно получить символ по коду ASCII, а также функция получения кода ASCII по символу?
Например:
А->65;
90->Z.

Comment: А они не нужны. Попробуйте:

printf ("%d\n",'A'); printf ("%c\n",90);

и Вы убедитесь, что символ и его ASCII код это одно и то же.

Comment: Мне нужно считать символ, который явялвется const char *, от него отнять 65('A'), таким образом  если прийдет на вход "A", то получится 0(координата первого элемента массива). Пример:
char c;
int x=c-'A';
cin>>c;

Таким образом мы получим в с - символ типа сonst char *, компилятор выдаст ошибку "cant convert const char * to int"...

Поетому мне нужно чтобы ASCII код символа был в переменной, дабы выполнить математические действия над ним...

Comment: !?!?!? А кавычки точно те поставили?

> Мне нужно считать символ, который явялвется const char *
бред. Символ не может быть const char*. Это указатель на константную строку (массив символов).

Comment: Кавычки те.

Comment: Я считываю в переменную с символ 'B' и отнимаю от него символ 'A'. Таким образом должно получится int x=с-'A'; тоесть 1, но компилятор выдает ошибку "cant convert const char * to int"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  char c;
  std::cout<<"enter symbol:"<<std::endl;
  std::cin>>c;
  int code;
  code = c - 'A';
  std::cout<<"code of symbol is "<<(int)c<<
       " and difference with 'A' is "   <<code<<std::endl;
  // в предыдущей строчке приведение к int нужно, иначе не сработает ООП-магия,
  // т.к. cout - это очень хитрый объект, определяющий по типу выводимого
  // выражения как его отобразить на экране
  return 1;
}
```

Прекрасно компилируется и работает

```
gaal@linux-lybs:~> g++ 1.cpp 
gaal@linux-lybs:~> ./a.out 
enter symbol:
A
code of symbol is 65 and difference with 'A' is 0
gaal@linux-lybs:~> ./a.out 
enter symbol:
B
code of symbol is 66 and difference with 'A' is 1
```

Comment: Проблему решила перестановка cin>>c перед перед code = c - 'A';
До этого просто выдавало -65)) 
Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3):

Судя по тегу у вас Си)
Преобразование символа в ASCII:

```
// C, with C type-casting
char cMyCharacter = 'A';
int iMyAsciiValue = (int)cMyCharacter;

// C++, with C++ type-casting
char cMyCharacter = 'A';
int iMyAsciiValue = static_cast<int>(cMyCharacter);
```

Преобразование кода в символ:

```
int asciiVal = 65;
char asciiChar = static_cast<char>(asciiVal);
```

или

```
char asciiChar = asciiVal;
```

Comment: По-моему, "// C, with C type-casting" это вообще не нужно, т.к. компилятор сам должен char привести к int'у. Примерно, как и `float` переменной можно присвоить значение `int` выражения (тоже будет автоматическое приведение типов).

Answer (score 0):

Функций таких нет - есть функции приведения типов.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    int ascii;
    cout << "Введите символ: ";
    cin >> c;
    cout << "ASCII-код: " << (int)c << endl;
    cout << "Введите ASCII-код символа: ";
    cin >> ascii;
    cout << "Cимвол: " << (char)ascii << endl;
    return 0;
}
```